# How can I deliver less-css context?

Tags: node.js, less

I need to delivery dynamic css content. In a short, I need this:

```
<link href="/css/site.css?color=111111" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

where site.css has unprocessed less code.

So I installed Node.js+LESS on server-side, and the follow line works fine:

```
$ lessc testless.less
```

But I still didn't figure out how to configure server to answer these HTTP requests.

1) What the best option: Using either apache or node.js? (I already have an apache server installed and working)

2) How should I configure my server and application to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Ronan

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest another preprocessor, which is based on JavaScript - http://krasimir.github.io/absurd/. The idea is to use JavaScript objects or JSON and generate CSS. Later, this CSS could be added to the document.

```
api.add({
    body: {
        marginTop: "20px",
        width: "100%"
    },
    header: {
        width: "100%"
    }
});
```

compiles to:

```
body {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
body, header {
  width: 100%;
}
```

AbsurdJS is available for a server-side (nodejs) or client-side usage. The good thing is that you can use everything which is available in the usual js code.

Comment: How do you ensure that the browser will apply the new <style></style> element to the document? Isn't this only parsed when the document is first loaded? Will it apply to the whole document?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same kind of problem to build http://twitterbootstrap3navbars.w3masters.nl/  and http://twitterbootstrap3buttons.w3masters.nl/. For both application i use apache with php.

For the button generator i used [Lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) and for the navbar generator i call lessc via PHP's exec().

I use less code to write inline stylsheets. In your case you would create a dynamic stylesheet.

So for example use:

`<link href="/css/site.php?color=111111" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

With site.php:

```
<?
//use lessphp from http://leafo.net/lessphp/
header("Content-type: text/css", true);
$less = new lessc;
echo $less->compile('p {color: '.$_GET['color'].'; }');
exit;
```

or

```
<?
//use lessc
header("Content-type: text/css", true);
exec( echo "p { color: '.$_GET['color'].'; }" | /usr/local/bin/lessc -',$output,$error);
echo implode("\n",$output);
exit;
```